# Failed to parse RSA publicKey in Java

Tags: java, security, rsa, bouncycastle, pkcs#8

I am using the following code block to parse any RSA public key to encrypt.

```
    static byte[] encrypt(byte[] publicKey, byte[] inputData) throws Exception {

    PublicKey key = KeyFactory.getInstance(ALGORITHM).generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKey));

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

    byte[] encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(inputData);

    return encryptedBytes;
}

public static String getEncrypted(String data, String key) throws Exception {
    byte[] keyBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(key);
    return new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(encrypt(keyBytes, data.getBytes())));
}
```

But for the following RSA public Key

```
MIIBCgKCAQEAs6YyGDXibkazM7QSeFBXjkAn5A8P87k+nuU6v5+zLJiD1KwkZ/SYnLwVSluOx19AzPHj07abDTJtthKtKpp2997UiV4CNUSzkZM1Eorf1+iLFhqeOiz9J5tYfFkKN5qPzwoPK4aFz35hQi7R1ORF9rFDPL+Ex79Tc+ABQF/CH5tn/NTXCNUYzLezg2Y1VOZGNhxd2LIv/29ZDxpJS8dD34H20HMMZCMGGolTXUIxVKI3cR0d1XzNCvAx3jcSkEUEPPH0lfusXqQOfCxJSIjorAzi5ucaWicvXYq6BNGulPqLoGBZnJ4HrFQF0oq1SU4i60VHqOgoiqMPQ+8cyjFBHQIDAQAB
```

while parsing I am getting the following exception

```
Caused by: java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException: algid parse error, not a sequence
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(RSAKeyFactory.java:205)
    at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePublic(KeyFactory.java:334)
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException: algid parse error, not a sequence
    at sun.security.x509.X509Key.decode(X509Key.java:397)
    at sun.security.x509.X509Key.decode(X509Key.java:402)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPublicKeyImpl.<init>(RSAPublicKeyImpl.java:86)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.generatePublic(RSAKeyFactory.java:298)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(RSAKeyFactory.java:201)
```

Any idea what is failing and how to make a generic RSA public key parsing code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [InvalidKeySpecException : algid parse error, not a sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31941413/invalidkeyspecexception-algid-parse-error-not-a-sequence)

Comment: @MWiesner I don't think so. The problem there is for Private key not in PKCS8 format. Whereas this is about parsing Public Key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is *analagous to* the problem in [InvalidKeySpecException : algid parse error, not a sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31941413/invalidkeyspecexception-algid-parse-error-not-a-sequence), though not the same. Just like PKCS8 is a generic format for private keys in (almost) any algorithm, by containing both an AlgorithmIdentifier that identifies the algorithm *and* algorithm-specific data, Java uses the generic format SubjectPublicKeyInfo (SPKI) [defined by X.509/PKIX](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1.2.7) for public keys, which Java calls `X509EncodedKeySpec`, containing an AlgId plus algorithm-specific data. (See the javadoc for `java.security.Key`; for some reason I am currently unable to access `docs.oracle.com` to get a link.) You have only the algorithm-specific data [defined by PKCS1 RSAPublicKey](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#appendix-A.1.1).

You can [parse and use it 'manually' with BouncyCastle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33425446/creating-rsa-public-key-from-string), or [convert it to SPKI and use that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54238568/reading-a-pkcs1-or-spki-public-key-in-java-without-libraries). Or (given BC or another ASN.1 library) you could use the same approach as in #31941413 except omit the Integer version (0) and wrap the data in a DERBitString instead of a DEROctetString, or the simpler and more direct approach I show in [RSA should I use X.509 or PKCS #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53924326/rsa-should-i-use-x-509-or-pkcs-1) .

Note this is not 'generic'. Your format is the opposite of algorithm-generic, which as noted is the purpose of SPKI and PCKS8. It is also not applciation-generic; among other things OpenSSH, PGP, Microsoft, PKCS11, JWK, and XML all use publickey formats different from this and not easily compatible with Java.

Comment: I have already figured out the issue  and wrote code to create publicKey from PKCS#1

Answer (score 2):

Your public key (here just the Base64-encoded part) seems to be a 'RSA Public Key'
and not a 'Public Key'. The later is the format that Java is been able to work with.

To read the 'RSA Public Key' you need the Bouncy Castle library and additional 7 lines of code. As you have the key without the 'wrapping' header and footer I add the two
line manually.

**Please keep in mind that the following code has no proper exception handling and is for educational purposes only.**

result:

```
key: Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  params: null
  modulus: 22678610734153400983507431374302231631648011897672768754638644005690558018788055145838420912495825001883497816406549666369767766949853573723573636289962789479998547620264293389522975840594912755684410510779642046063268111520844008640320545114702934792800828432077361704284837605938354936920018742130341245366517474980128047515437565419306561322350155414838564407700303406271838590880852369997316303577351737008942081641382006211591786506015023574950120763293965668830106827392978781367691242570394862298000041087969687942746452359360224223895623579995775734139473237799095359767270215802792812274542667250920043135261
  public exponent: 65537
```

code:

```
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.SubjectPublicKeyInfo;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMParser;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;

public class MainSO {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        System.out.println("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63454577/failed-to-parse-rsa-publickey-in-java");
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        String rsaPublicKeyHeader = "-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\n";
        String rsaPublicKeyFooter = "\n-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----";
        String rsaPublicKeyString = "MIIBCgKCAQEAs6YyGDXibkazM7QSeFBXjkAn5A8P87k+nuU6v5+zLJiD1KwkZ/SYnLwVSluOx19AzPHj07abDTJtthKtKpp2997UiV4CNUSzkZM1Eorf1+iLFhqeOiz9J5tYfFkKN5qPzwoPK4aFz35hQi7R1ORF9rFDPL+Ex79Tc+ABQF/CH5tn/NTXCNUYzLezg2Y1VOZGNhxd2LIv/29ZDxpJS8dD34H20HMMZCMGGolTXUIxVKI3cR0d1XzNCvAx3jcSkEUEPPH0lfusXqQOfCxJSIjorAzi5ucaWicvXYq6BNGulPqLoGBZnJ4HrFQF0oq1SU4i60VHqOgoiqMPQ+8cyjFBHQIDAQAB";
        PEMParser pemParser = new PEMParser(new StringReader(rsaPublicKeyHeader +
                rsaPublicKeyString + rsaPublicKeyFooter));
        SubjectPublicKeyInfo subjectPublicKeyInfo = (SubjectPublicKeyInfo) pemParser.readObject();
        byte[] publicKey = subjectPublicKeyInfo.getEncoded();
        // original code starts here
        PublicKey key = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKey));
        // check key
        System.out.println("key: " + key);
    }
}
```