# How to encrypt data with RSA PublicKey in java?

Tags: java, encryption, rsa

I have a json response with parameters:

```
 "jwk":{
    "kty": "string",
    "n": "string",
    "e": "string",
    "alg": "string",
    "ext": bool
  },
 "pem": "--BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY--...SOMEKEY...--END RSA PUBLIC KEY--",
 "alg": {
    "name": "string",
    "hash": {
        "name": "string
    }
 }
}
```

I need to encrypt data with RSA Public key.
I'm trying to get "pem", clear it and create public key

```
String clearKey = rsaKey.replace("--BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY--", "").replace("--END RSA PUBLIC KEY--", "").replace("\\s","");
byte[] prByte = Base64.getDecoder().decode(clearKey);
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstanse("RSA");
keyFactory.generatePrivate(new PKCS8EEncodedKeySpec(prByte));
```

but on this step I have an error

```
:java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException: algid parse error not a sequence
```

this code followed by error too

```
byte[] prByte = Base64.getDecoder().decode(clearKey);
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(prBytes);
PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic("keySpec"):
```

I know that RSA PUBLIC KEY maybe should be mapped on RSAPublicKey but for this i need "n" and "e" attributes?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here?  Surely not to generate the private key corresponding to the public key you have received?  Because the security of RSA encryption depends on that not being practical.

Comment: From this json, as I understand, I need to get RSA key and encrypt data using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no PEM format for RSA publickey that begins and ends with the strings you show: ALL PEM formats start with FIVE hyphens, uppercase 'BEGIN', a label or type description of one or more uppercase words, FIVE hyphens, AND A LINEBREAK; this is followed by one or more lines of base64, and then a similar line with 'END' instead of 'BEGIN' and *optionally* the linebreak after the 'END' line may be omitted. [See wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy-Enhanced_Mail) and as referenced there [RFC 7468](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7468).

If your 'PEM' is actually in the format I (and wikipedia and 7468) describe and not what you posted, then it is the 'traditional' format defined by OpenSSL (originally SSLeay) based on the simple and straightforward [ASN.1 format defined by PKCS1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#appendix-A.1.1). This is not the same format as the X.509 'SPKI' (SubjectPublicKeyInfo) format defined by X.509 and used by Java as `X509EncodedKeySpec`. (It is even more different from the PKCS8 format used by Java for privatekeys as `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec`, because a publickey is not a privatekey.) It is however *related*, because the SPKI format actually is an ASN.1 SEQUENCE containing an AlgorithmIdentifier which (surprise!) identifies the algorithm plus a BIT STRING containing algorithm-specific data and *for RSA* the algorithm-specific data *is* PKCS1 `RSAPublicKey`, so as a result the DER encoding of the SPKI for an RSA key contains as a suffix the PKCS1 data found in an OpenSSL-defined `BEGIN/END RSA PUBLIC KEY` file.

There are two ways to directly use this 'traditional' PEM format:

1. construct the SPKI format for the same key by building the ASN.1 'wrapper', and then feed that to `KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA") .generatePublic( new X509EncodedKeySpec( spki ))`.
2. use bcpkix+bcprov from https://www.bouncycastle.org whose `PEMParser` class combined with `JcaPEMKeyConverter` can directly handle traditional RSA publickey (among many other formats).

Both of these methods have been asked and answered several times. See:
[How to load RSA public key from String for signature verification in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54957545/how-to-load-rsa-public-key-from-string-for-signature-verification-in-java)
[Reading a PKCS#1 or SPKI public key in Java without libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54238568/reading-a-pkcs1-or-spki-public-key-in-java-without-libraries)
[Failed to parse RSA publicKey in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63454577/failed-to-parse-rsa-publickey-in-java)
[RSA should I use X.509 or PKCS #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53924326/rsa-should-i-use-x-509-or-pkcs-1) (and more linked there)
[How can I transform between the two styles of public key format, one "BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY", the other is "BEGIN PUBLIC KEY"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039401/how-can-i-transform-between-the-two-styles-of-public-key-format-one-begin-rsa) (background but not Java)

The similar problem of converting PKCS1 *privatekey* to PKCS8 also comes up quite a bit. I wrote an answer for the equivalent of approach 1 (i.e. 'wrap' the PKCS1 privatekey to give PKCS8) in [Java: Convert DKIM private key from RSA to DER for JavaMail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23709898/java-convert-dkim-private-key-from-rsa-to-der-for-javamail) and two other people did similarly in [Getting RSA private key from PEM BASE64 Encoded private key file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7216969/getting-rsa-private-key-from-pem-base64-encoded-private-key-file) . Modifying my approach in #23709898 for publickey-to-SPKI instead of privatekey-to-PKCS8 gives:

```
    // input: b64 contains the base64 _data_ from a BEGIN/END RSA PUBLIC KEY file
    // (i.e. with the BEGIN/END lines and linebreaks removed)
    byte[] oldder = Base64.getDecoder().decode (b64);

    // concatenate the mostly-fixed prefix plus the PKCS#1 data 
    final byte[] prefix = {0x30,(byte)0x82,0,0, // SEQUENCE(lenTBD) 
            0x30,0x0d, 6,9,0x2a,(byte)0x86,0x48,(byte)0x86,(byte)0xf7,0x0d,1,1,1, 5,0, // AlgID for rsaEncryption,NULL
            3,(byte)0x82,0,0,0 }; // BITSTRING(lenTBD) + unused
    byte[] newder = new byte [prefix.length + oldder.length];
    System.arraycopy (prefix,0, newder,0, prefix.length);
    System.arraycopy (oldder,0, newder,prefix.length, oldder.length);
    // and patch the (variable) lengths to be correct
    int len = oldder.length+1, loc = prefix.length-3; 
    newder[loc] = (byte)(len>>8); newder[loc+1] = (byte)len;
    len = newder.length-4; loc = 2;
    newder[loc] = (byte)(len>>8); newder[loc+1] = (byte)len;

    PublicKey pubkey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA") .generatePublic( new X509EncodedKeySpec( newder ));
```

But since you also have the JWK form you additionally have a third option:

3. get the jwk n and e values (from whatever JSON classes/representation you are using), convert each to (positive) BigInteger, put them in `RSAPublicKeySpec` and run that through the `KeyFactory`:

```
    BigInteger n = new BigInteger(1, Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode( jwk.n ));
    BigInteger e = new BigInteger(1, Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode( jwk.e ));
    PublicKey pubkey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA") .generatePublic( new RSAPublicKeySpec(n,e) ));
```

Comment: Yes. The pem is really starts with "-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----". But the public key 
PublicKey pubkey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA") .generatePublic( new RSAPublicKeySpec(n,e) ));  isn't working. I send it to the decryption service and it can't be decrypted by private key. And the keys are 100% valid.

Comment: Does the alg in jwk playing some role? IT is RSA-OAEP-256, or alg name RSA-OAEP and hash SHA-256

Comment: [jwk.alg specifies with which algorithm(s) the key is _supposed_ to be used](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7517#section-4.4). In general this information is not present in the X.509-SPKI format although it _optionally_ may for [RSA PSS and OAEP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4055). Java does implement the PSS variant key, probably because it is strongly encouraged though not strictly required for TLSv1.3, but AFAICT does not implement the OAEP variant key, and doing so by hand would be quite a pain. Did you encrypt with OAEP _and_ SHA256? If the key owner says they want that ...

Comment: ... it's probably required. Do you (need to) send the data in a format that uses an AlgorithmIdentifier? If so you may need to do it by hand, per above; if so add to your Q and I'll work that part out when I have more time. But if you're sending in JWE format, the algorithm info is specified only in the key not the data. Anyway if you want an answer post specifics (usually documentation) of what the 'service' wants.